# If stament showing a error with closing bracket

Tags: php, syntax-error

Hello im trying to make a few random numbers and do a simple mysql update but for some reason Dreamweaver is showing a error on the closing bracket.

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['battle_move'])) {

$battle_move= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['battle_move']);
$battle_move22 = strip_tags($battle_move);
$random_number = rand(1, 50); 
$a = $random_number ;
$b = 5;
$random_number1 = ($a * $b) ;


$random_number2 = rand(1, 50); 
$c = $random_number2 ;
$d = 5;
$random_number22 = ($c * $d) ;

mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET wildpokemonhp=wildpokemonhp+".$random_number1." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET userpokemonhp=userpokemonhp+".$random_number22." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")

    }
?>
```

I upload it to my server and get a white page. I have never ever come across this be for... Its saying the last } is the problem.....

Comment: you missed the semi colon at the end of the two mysql_query... statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `;` on the `mysql_query` seems to be the problem.

Comment: note. generally an error message in php doesnt relate directly to what its pointing you to. Thats the point the error was caught. Its often easier to look at the previous lines or previous statement.... :) just a tip

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET wildpokemonhp=wildpokemonhp+".$random_number1." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET userpokemonhp=userpokemonhp+".$random_number22." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

You need to have a `;` after each mysql_query

Comment: Thanks can't believe i forgot that

Answer (score 2):

You left ; in query updates. Please correct them.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET wildpokemonhp=wildpokemonhp+".$random_number1." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET userpokemonhp=userpokemonhp+".$random_number22." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Comment: Thanks can't believe i forgot that

Answer (score 2):

Try terminator (`;`) at the end of `mysql_query()` statements:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET wildpokemonhp=wildpokemonhp+".$random_number1." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET userpokemonhp=userpokemonhp+".$random_number22." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing ; on:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET wildpokemonhp=wildpokemonhp+".$random_number1." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE maplog SET userpokemonhp=userpokemonhp+".$random_number22." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls. write ";" after each php command.